# Cocoa App webview not loading request

Tags: webview, macos-sierra, xcode9, swift4

I have used webview to load url but it is not loaded.

i have tried the same with wkwebview but couldn't load url.

I have done following

- import WebKit
- Info.plist

  - Allow Arbitrary Loads - YES
  - Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content - YES

LOG:

dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1

dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2

dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:11 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted

nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)

-CODE

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webvw: WebView!

 override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.co.in") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        webvw.uiDelegate = self
        webvw.frameLoadDelegate = self
        webvw.mainFrame.load(request)
    }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Check capabilities > Incoming and outgoing connections

Comment: When I called Host.current().name from my macOS app I got "macos dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed". This answer fixes my problem like a charm.

Answer (score 13):

Select target

1. find capabilities
2. Turn on app sand box if it's off
3. Tick both network option

done

Answer (score 7):

@Rakshit Korat had the answer.  For a visual answer:

**xCode 11**

Under Target / Signing & Capabilities / App Sandbox.

[image]