# Swift - Is it possible to ping a RTMP Url?

Tags: ios, swift, url, ping, rtmp

I wanted to know if it's possible to ping a RTMP Url like `rtmp://192.168.xx.xx/live/mykey` and how

To know if my RTMP url is **reachable**

I already tried but didn't work for **Rtmp Url**: [Ping a Website or an IP Address (or Check if a Website is Online) using Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512244/ping-a-website-or-an-ip-address-or-check-if-a-website-is-online-using-swift-4)

Best regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not strictly. PING is it’s own protocol. Just like pinging any computer does not tell you if it’s running a web server. You must connect the the RTMP endpoint, and handshake. You can then disconnect without sending any flv tags.