# How to check if internet is not working with swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have Implemented internet check in my code which is working perfectly fine, but There is an issue !
Let say if Device is connected to a wifi BUT internet is not working, limited access or internet is down from some reason..
How to identify this any suggestions any best practice ???

Comment: [You can try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518310/5698778)

Comment: just use this pod simple and efficient https://cocoapods.org/pods/Reachability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it using `NWPathMonitor`. for implementation, you need to follow the following steps.

**Step 1:**

```
import Network
```

**Step 2:**

create an instance of NWPathMonitor somewhere it won’t get freed immediately. For example, you might have it as a property on a view controller, for example:

```
let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
```

**Step 3:**

Now assign a closure to that monitor that will be triggered whenever network accessibility changes. This needs to accept one parameter, which is an NWPath describing the network access that is currently possible.

```
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    if path.status == .satisfied {
        print("We're connected!")
    } else {
        print("No connection.")
    }

    print(path.isExpensive)
}
```

**Source:** https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-nwpathmonitor